# Bootstrap Navigation: menu item linking and dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to achieve the following with the Navbar from Bootstrap:

1) Top Menu Items: Mouse-Over effect to show the sub menu items

This can be solved using:

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
   display: block;    
}
```

2) Top Menu Items: Click will open the link
This can be achieved removing the

```
data-toggle="toggle"
```

and

```
class="toggle"
```

attributes from the links

3) In the responsive view on a mobile phone it should NOT open the link after clicking BUT it should toggle the drop-down-effect what happens after changing the code with 1) and 2)

Here's an example link: http://jsfiddle.net/AZ6fs/1/

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Number 3) is the behavior I want to achieve, so the question is: How do I achieve that :/

Comment: I'm still confused on what you are trying to accomplish. Are you saying you want the dropdown menus to toggle by hovering over, except on mobile platforms you want them to have the default behavior of toggling by clicks?

Comment: Yes, 
on desktop views: Clicking on the top menu entry will take you to the target. Hovering will show the submenu.


Mobile view:
Clicking will only toggle the submenus open. Only clicking on a submenu item will bring you to the target page